# Application Crashes on phone using BufferedReader

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

i'm a noob in android development.

I made an application that gets lines from a textfile located to an url and add them into a vector.

It doesn't work on my smartphone (Xperia U) but works in android virtual machine (Nexus One).

Logcat doesn't show any error, so removing codelines 1 by 1 i found the problem: BufferedReader

Here's the part of code i've to change... i call it into main activity... what can i do?

```
    URL url = new URL(// an url);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String str;

    this.names=new Vector<String>();
    this.links=new Vector<String>();

    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] splitted = str.split("#"); 
        names.add(splitted[0].toString());
        links.add(splitted[1].toString());
    }
        in.close();
```

Comment: "Logcat doesn't show any error" Is this code in a try-catch block?

Comment: check if your instance of BufferedReader is null before trying to read from it?

Comment: yes it is in try-catch block but it works well on virtual machine...

Comment: Please post the entire try-catch code, you probably aren't displaying the error (`e.printStackTrace()`).

Comment: @ryanbwork It can't possibly be null in this code.

Comment: there's no error in try and catch. it just doesn't work on smartphone... I'm reading about asynctask, could be this solve the problem?

Comment: Again, please post the entire try-catch code. If the app crashes there is an error. If it doesn't crash then this line makes no sense: "removing codelines 1 by 1 i found the problem: BufferedReader"...